# Iterate through an array of DIVs and fadeIn/fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, wait

I want to build a simple banner image slider functionality, but instead of sliding, the images are supposed to fade in and out.

It's a Drupal project, so I don't know how many images are going to be used.
The structure is simple enough:

```
<div class="banner-container">
  <!-- potentially a lot of divs with background images -->
</div>
```

What I want to do is essentially iterate through this "array" of divs let the currently active one fade out and let the one that the array is pointing to at the moment fade in.

I thought I could get it to work like this:

```
var a = $('#banner-container').children();

while(1) {
  a.each(function(){
    $('.active').fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
    $(this).fadeIn(500).addClass('.active');
  })
}
```

Obviously there is a lot wrong in my code, I have run into multiple issues, but the one I cannot seem to solve is getting the loop to wait between the iterations. To my knowledge, a traditional loop like `foreach` could just have some sort of `wait` function added to the end of it and execute that `wait` in every loop. But the `.each()` seems to execute every iteration simultaneously. How can I loop through an array like this (potentially infinitely) and wait like 5 seconds every time?

I read somewhere that the `animate` functions work asynchronously, and I assume the same goes for CSS transforms, so creating `fadeIn`, and `fadeOut` classes and try this with CSS wouldn't work.

Comment: Please provide actual HTML structure. I mean the inner part of `<div class="banner-container">`

Comment: Side note: `.addClass('.active');` should be `.addClass('active');` (no `.` in front of `active`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) and [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) functions: You pass a function into them with a timeout (in milliseconds), and they call the function after that many milliseconds (repeating, in the case of `setInterval`).

So for instance:

```
var a = $('#banner-container').children();
var index = 0;
run();
function run() {
  a.filter('.active').fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
  a.eq(index).fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
  index = (index + 1) % a.length; // Wraps around if it hits the end
  setTimeout(run, 1000);
}
```

That will update the first div, then a second later the next div, and so on.

**Live Example:**

```js
// Scoping function to avoid creating globals
(function() {
  var a = $('#banner-container').children();
  var index = 0;
  run()

  function run() {
    a.filter('.active').fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
    a.eq(index).fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
    index = (index + 1) % a.length; // Wraps around if it hits the end
    setTimeout(run, 1000);
  }
})();
```

```css
#banner-container a {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#banner-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner-container">
  <a>one</a>
  <a>two</a>
  <a>three</a>
  <a>four</a>
  <a>five</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the above, I've used `setTimeout`, which only schedules a *single* callback, because I find I write fewer bugs when the thing I'm calling has to explicitly re-schedule the next call. :-) But you could also use `setInterval(run, 1000);` which would call `run` at roughly one-second intervals, until/unless you told it to stop via [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval).

Comment: Oh maaaaaaaaaaaaaaan, I knew about setTimeout, but I never thought about using it to make a recursion.. Now it works, thanks TJ.

Comment: @Pamblam: LOL Yeah, I love that one. If your counter is 1-based you do `index = index % maxValueInclusive + 1` insead.

Comment: @Pamblam: If you wouldn't mind deleting that first comment, it'll save a mod a bit of time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use a loop for this because of the nature of javascript, you will have to use recursion instead, something like this untested code should work..

```
function loopNext(currentIndex){
     // set the current index on the first call
     if('undefined' === typeof currentIndex) currentIndex=0;

     // the group of image divs
     var images = $(".imagesDivs");

     // if the current index doesn't exist, 
     // we've looped thru them all, reset the index
     if('undefined' === typeof images.eq(currentIndex)) currentIndex=0;

     // fade out the previous one and fade in the first one
     images.fadeOut('slow', function(){
         images.eq(currentIndex).fadeIn('slow');
     });

     // fade the next one every 3 seconds or so
     setTimeout(function(){
          loopNext(currentIndex+1);
     }, 3000);
}
```

To start the loop you can just call it without any parameters..

```
loopNext();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [setTimout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and go to the next element or start over:

```
setTimout(function(){
     var current = $('.active');
     var next = current.next().length > 0 ? current.next() : $('.banner-container > div').first(); 
     current.fadeOut(500).removeClass('active');
     next.fadeIn(500).addClass('.active');
},5000);
```